# how to call python module with package name

Tags: python, module, package

I want to make a distributable python module, so I want to make users **call functions inside of my module via just calling package name.**

**e.g.**

> /my_package/ 
> /my_package/__init__.py 
> /my_package/src/ 
> /my_package/src/__init__.py 
> /my_package/src/my_module.py

and, the contents of mymodule.py:

> def test(): print('hello!')

in this case, I want to let users use my module like:

> >>> import mypackage as mp 
> >>> mp.test() 
> hello!

just like tensorflow, numpy, etc. !!!

How should I configure __init__.py file and path info??

Answer (score 2):

In the file:

`/my_package/__init__.py`

add the line:

```
from src.my_module import test
```

Comment: One more question... If I want to "hide" the internal packages, what should I do??
e.g.
if the repository has "MyClass" in /my_package/src/my_module.py, it returns "<class my_package.src.my_module.MyClass .. blah blah>" when users type "type(MyClassInstance)" on console.
I want to show it like: <class my_package.MyClass .. blah blah>

Any suggestions?? I've already tried to change the string of self.__module__, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you don't just want to expose `test` function but a lot of other functions. So, you can separately maintain a `__all__` list in your `my_package/__init__.py` that exposes any external methods to be used by others.

So, your `my_package/__init__.py` would look like

```
from src.my_module import test


__all__ = [test, ]
```

You can read about `__all__` here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package